# 3rd party SQL import stops on import of SQL file giving error: #1068 - Multiple primary key defined

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1068

I have a 3rd party software and I exported the database structure so that I can import it on another computer. I guess a few tables have multiple primary keys but how can I import the tables witout MySQL stopping the import because it has detected multi primary keys?

This is the error I get:

> 1068 - Multiple primary key defined

I have defined this into the sql file.

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
```

and the import still stops on import when it detects multi primary keys.
is there anything else I can do??

thanks

Comment: The dump you've shared doesn't even create a table. Can you share more details?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple primary keys.  You can, however, have one primary key that is made up of multiple attributes.  Make sure you are in fact trying to only create a single primary key.  Disabling foreign keys will not make a difference here because the two things are not related.

I would check what create table or alter table statements you are using and make sure they are all creating a single primary key.

My guess is this software is taking a multi-attribute primary key and trying to create a primary key for each of the attributes.